# Ignore Records where a field has NULL value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any function to ignore records where a particular column value is null. I have created a left outer join (includes 4 tables) and populates some records. In this join, there is a field called "Tab Desc". Whenever this field has NULL values I want to ignore those records.

Please advise.

Baskar

Comment: Is this a nullable column in the 'outer' table or is it a null created as a result of using outer join? If it is the latter, consider not using outer join!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you show the query I could give a more complete answer, but try adding something like `WHERE TabDesc IS NOT NULL` to your query.

EDIT: If TabDesc is a field you are joining on then do not use an outer join and it should solve your problem.

Comment: +1 To clarify: use an *inner* join instead of an *outer* join.